# jQueryUI tabs disable method not working: disables all tabs when it should not

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

When I call the disable method, all the jQueryUI tabs become disabled, including the one (index 1) I left out of the index array.  Here is a sample:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs1">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs2">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs3">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs4">four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs5">five</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs1" style="display: none;"><p>tab 1 content</p></div>
  <div id="tabs2" style="display: none;"><p>tab 2 content</p></div>
  <div id="tabs3" style="display: none;"><p>tab 3 content</p></div>
  <div id="tabs4" style="display: none;"><p>tab 4 content</p></div>
  <div id="tabs5" style="display: none;"><p>tab 5 content</p></div>
</div>

<script>
    function disableAllExcept1(){
        $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'disabled', [0,2,3,4,5]);
        $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active', 1);
    }

    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        disableAllExcept1();
    });
</script>
```

Why is it disabling tab two (index 1)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an extra index in the array.  I had removed a tab but had not removed the index (5) from the array.  The behavior seems odd though, maybe even buggy.  I would expect it to just ignore the extra index or emit a warning or error.

This:

```
$('#tabs').tabs('option', 'disabled', [0,2,3,4,5]);
```

Should have been this:

```
$('#tabs').tabs('option', 'disabled', [0,2,3,4]);
```

Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/spencerw/hmno6ekb/